# Blank screen when running Sveltejs template on M1 MacBook Air

Tags: javascript, npm, terminal, svelte

I am in the process of learning Sveltejs and until now I have been using https://svelte.dev/repl/ to go through the tutorial, which has been working perfectly.

However, I wanted to develop and run Sveltejs applications from my machine (MacBook Air M1) - so I downloaded the provided sveltejs file and opened it in VS Code.

I installed the node_modules `npm install`. Then, I ran `npm run dev` which doesn't seem to produce an error

[Screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZrKL.png)

Nevertheless, when I open http://localhost:5000, I am presented with a blank page, and going on 'Inspect Element' presents me with an empty webpage: [Screenshot of localhost:5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGHuw.png)

I downloaded this template from https://svelte.dev/repl/ - I did not make any changes to this project yet it still malfunctions.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

It should be noted that I am new to web development and the node package manager.

Comment: Have any code in your App.svelte file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem on the M1 mac (actually it is probably due to oSX Catalina not the M1 specifically but I haven’t checked on an intel running Catalina) is that port 5000 is in use by command center.  This means that svelte can't bind to that port.

To see what ports are active on your mac run the command

```
lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN
```

When you run npm run dev you can set the port to something else that is not in conflict...This is what I ran.

```
PORT=54321 npm run dev
```

That should fix it and run for you.

Then you will access it on

http://localhost:54321

Comment: Also if you want to configure the port in your package.json file so you don't have to type specify the port at the command line each time you can do it with --environment flag.  "dev": "rollup -c -w --environment PORT:54321"

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you start your svelte projest you need this command:

```
npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project
```

after you go to your project:

```
cd my-svelte-project
```

and when you are in this project you run:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

after npm run dev normally you have an information on witch port application runs.

Then you go to src and App.svelte and you remplace code by default by your code.
Normally it has to work.

Did you have a welcome page of svelte before you put your code?

[here](https://youtu.be/3TVy6GdtNuQ) you have a good tutorial of svelte.

Comment: I use also MacBook Air.

Comment: These instructions don't seem to work - I still see a blank page (on Safari), however I have tried it out on Google Chrome and I am seeing a message saying 'Access to localhost was denied', the error code is 403. Any help?

Comment: Look on your proxy or security, or firewall and you deactivate it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however the answer from Gildo T Baggins has solved my error.